Cannot fetch an element from an OWLAPI OWLOntology
I am trying to find a specific element in a loaded OWLOntology but cannot. I loaded a document that contains the following statements:
<http://www.adventium.com/aadl> rdf:type owl:Ontology ;
     http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1#title "AADL Language Terms" .
http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1#title rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty .

Here is the code I used.  Why doesn't it list the OWLLiteral "AADL Language Terms"?
OWLOntology owlOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(workingIRI);
final OWLOntologyID ontologyID = owlOntology.getOntologyID();
final Optional<IRI> ontoIRI = ontologyID.getOntologyIRI();
final OWLNamedIndividual ontologyIndividual = dataFactory
    .getOWLNamedIndividual(ontoIRI.get())
final OWLAnnotationProperty titleAnnotation = dataFactory
    .getOWLAnnotationProperty(IRI.create("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1#title"));
final Stream<OWLAnnotation> titleAnnotations = EntitySearcher
    .getAnnotations(ontologyIndividual, owlOntology, titleAnnotation);
final List<OWLAnnotation> titleAnnotationList = titleAnnotations.toList();
for (final OWLAnnotation annotation : titleAnnotationList) {
    final OWLLiteral literal = (OWLLiteral) annotation.getValue();
    final String title = literal.getLiteral();
    System.err.println("title " + title);
}

I expected it to output the string "AADL Language Terms"

Ontology annotations are not annotation axioms, they're stored separately. Check OWLOntology::getAnnotations(OWLOntology)

The closest OWLOntology method I could find is "default Set getAnnotations(OWLAnnotationProperty annotationProperty); Gets the annotations whose annotation property is equal to annotationProperty."  I could find nothing whose parameter is another OWLOntology object.

I am searching for AnnotationAssertion( http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1#title http://www.adventium.com/aadl "a string literal" )

To put it another way, I want to get the list of statements/triples
http://www.adventium.com/aadl http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1#title "a string literal"
If it makes any difference, http://www.adventium.com/aadl isa owl:Ontology, and http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1#title isa owl:AnnotationProperty.
